# Drupal 7: Dynamic first segment of a path with Panels

Tags: path, drupal-7, arguments, drupal-panels

I am working to create dynamic landing pages for a site, using panels. The first step in the process is to designate the path. I want the landing pages to have the same path as the nodes, just ending in "home" for the landing page. For example, I have "departments" that will have landing pages, so the path looks like:

department/%department_name/home

That works fine. However, I am also trying to create a series of paths based on a set of vocabularies. They all have different names, but they work essentially the same. I want this:

%vocabulary/%terms/home

But then I get this error:

**"The first element in a path may not be dynamic."**

Why not? I don't want to have to create variants for each vocabulary. Isn't there some way to by-pass this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot by-pass this error. Drupal's menu system simply does not support % as the first placeholder.

See an explanation at a [related Drupal.org discussion](https://drupal.org/node/370868).

A simple solution here is to **use a generic static argument for the whole site** (like site, live, new etc) as a starter path. Some developers also use this by default so they can alter it later on upcoming versions or on new functionality (for example they may have path /a/%some_args and a new version will be /b/%some_args).